# Get hyperlinks for attachment evernote note

Tags: evernote

We are not getting hyperlinks for attachments in getting the note information using note Id.please help us to get hyperlink for attachments

Comment: Can you specify what you did in detail and provide code snippet you use? I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do though Evernote API doesn't provide URLs to each attachment.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply
I am adding attachment in note.for that my web hook triggered.I got response like userId, guid, notebook guid, reason.With the guid i am getting note information.

Comment: Note information response is (guid:0fcb75c8-f12b-4097-bc74-3b35caaa291f, title:Enterprise, contentHash:A2 02 F6 F9 73 BB 72 21 09 49 76 36 36 6C BE 26, contentLength:257, created:1487774308000, updated:1487779886000, active:true, updateSequenceNum:379, notebookGuid:6e4276db-0b27-420f-8d71-9f015c6af108, resources:

Comment: [Resource(guid:b235b50b-baa8-4417-bb07-94401902b8f1, noteGuid:0fcb75c8-f12b-4097-bc74-3b35caaa291f, data:Data(bodyHash:56 00 2E D7 2D DE 9A 15 48 EF 24 A6 03 1E DC AC, size:43715), mime:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, active:true, attributes:ResourceAttributes(fileName:Application Log.docx, attachment:true), updateSequenceNum:380)], attributes:NoteAttributes(author:ekpradeep, reminderOrder:1487778537198, reminderTime:1486780200000)).In the above I got only the fie name.We need a hyperlink for that file.

Comment: Is it possible get or construct hyperlink for that attachment?

Answer (score 0):

The `Downloading a resource through the API` section in [this page](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/resources.php#downloading) is probably the one you want to know. The URL should look like `[webApiUrlPrefix]/res/[resource GUID]`.